# How to use CLLocation extension in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift3, cllocation, rx-swift

I want to use `CLLocationManager` with `RxSwift` like in 
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/413
 but I found that `CLLocationManager` extension was moved to `RxExample` 
(mentioned here https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/900).

My question is: how to use that code? When I import `RxSwift` and `RxCocoa` I don't have access to e.g. `locationManager.rx.didUpdateLocations`. What should I do so that I can use `CoreLocation` with `RxSwift`?

I'm using Xcode 8, Swift 3.

Thanks in advance for your help!

### Update

I found that it is recommended that for now we must just copy & paste `CLLocationManager` extension from `RxExample` (details [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/commit/2e8736b137064101cd98ee01523e6229825cecce#commitcomment-18981218) in comments of that commit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to copy the extension CLLocationManager+Rx.swift and RxCLLocationManagerDelegateProxy.swift to your project as it is no longer part of RxCocoa

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who finds this through Google, Rx Location Manager functionality has been moved to: https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxCoreLocation so there is no longer a need to manually copy and paste files.